# Hide the documentation source file link in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Doxygen shows at the end of each html file the text "The document for this ... was generated from the following file..."
Is it possible to remove this text by using an option in the doxyfile?

Comment: I think this is done by means of `SHOW_USED_FILES`

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the aid of the configuration parameter `SHOW_USED_FILES` it is possible to disable the sentence ""The documentation for this...".

From the documentation:

> SHOW_USED_FILES
>
> Set the SHOW_USED_FILES tag to NO to disable the list
> of files generated at the bottom of the documentation of classes and
> structs. If set to YES, the list will mention the files that were used
> to generate the documentation.
>
> The default value is: YES.